# Python receiving serial data

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to send a message from Python 3.6 to Arduino and the Arduino needs to respond.

At the moment I am able to send to the Arduino and it responds but instead of getting a full message back I get 1 byte.

Arduino code:

```cpp
byte FullResponse[] = {0xA1, 0xA3, 0xA4, 0x3B, 0x1F, 0xB4, 0x1F, 0x74, 0x19, 
0x79, 0x44, 0x9C, 0x1F, 0xD4, 0x4A, 0xC0};
byte SerialBuf[11] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
//Reads values from the Serial port, if there are any
  for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    while(!Serial.available());
    SerialBuf[i] = Serial.read();
  }

//Sends the full response back if EF is the 8th byte
  if(SerialBuf[8] == 0xEF){
     Serial.write(FullResponse, sizeof(FullResponse));
     SerialBuf[8] = 15;
  }
}
```

Python code:

```py
## import the serial library
import serial
import time

Response = []
FullResponse = bytes([0xC0, 0x43, 0xA1, 0x04, 0x0A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x30, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xC0])

## Serial port is 
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200)
time.sleep(2)

#converts values to byte array and sends to arduino
ConArray = bytearray(FullResponse)
ser.write(ConArray[0:len(FullResponse)])
time.sleep(1)    
    
if ser.inWaiting():
    for Val in ser.read():
        Response.append(Val)

print(*Response)        #prints 161
print(len(Response))        #prints 1

time.sleep(1)

## close the port and end the program
ser.close()
```

As you can see from the comments I left in the python code. Instead of getting a whole array of values I merely receive 161.

Does any one have any advice for where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By changing the if statement to a while statement the code now reads all the bytes saved. Thank you for the help Heyyo

```
## import the serial library
import serial
import time

Response = []
FullResponse = bytes([0xC0, 0x43, 0xA1, 0x04, 0x0A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x30, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xC0])

## Serial port is 
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=115200)
time.sleep(2)

#converts values to byte array and sends to arduino
ConArray = bytearray(FullResponse)
ser.write(ConArray[0:len(FullResponse)])
time.sleep(1)    

while ser.inWaiting(): ###########   Changed from if to while
    for Val in ser.read():
        Response.append(Val)

print(*Response)        #prints 161
print(len(Response))        #prints 1

time.sleep(1)

## close the port and end the program
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read) of `Serial.read()` function you will see that its default argument is '1'. So it reads only 1 byte from the serial port as expected. You should first check if (or wait until) there are enough bytes and pass number of bytes you want to read to the `read()` function.

Comment: You Beautiful Genius. Thank you.